# Return a entity with a subset of a map

Tags: java, criteria, openjpa

i use OpenJPA with an Oracle DB. 
For example, i have a entity that have a Map like this:

```
@ElementCollection
private Map<Integer, String> mapWithKeys;
```

Now, i want load a entity with a subset of the map entries. For example i want load the entity with all map entrys that have the keys "1","3," or "5". Is that possible with JPA Criteria? I didnt find anything about it. I've tried it with a MapJoin, but if one value match the whole map would be load.

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a little function that fetches the entries one by one.

Comment: okay, i thought there is an easy way to filter the map data with one Criteria Query.

Comment: I don't think there is. If you want anything like that you'd need to use something like SQLite.
On the other hand it is pretty easy to write something like that from scratch.